# How can I calculate if one box is overlap​ to another in Opencv Python​?

Tags: python, opencv, math, image-processing, geometry

How can I calculate if one box is  overlap​​ to another in Opencv Python​​ ?

This is Shape 1 : [[ shape 1 ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyz6m.png)

This is Shape 2 : [[ shape 2 ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHcbW.png)

What I need is know the shape 1  overlap with shape 2 or Not ?

result that i should get :

False : [If it not contiguous each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yGRW.png)

True : [If it not contiguous each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Ry7.png)

#I spend 3 day to solve this problem but still cannot find a way to go out hope you can help me :)

Comment: Does this help ? https://answers.opencv.org/question/67091/how-to-find-if-2-rectangles-are-overlapping-each-other/

Comment: it really help me a lots , it help me to get more information to research , any way thanks you so much . but those source code is not python langue it hard to understant , – 
if you don't mine can you help Lead the way​ to me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function inputs are 4-element tuple is used.You can improve this code for your problem.

```
def intersection(a,b):
  x = max(a[0], b[0])
  y = max(a[1], b[1])
  w = min(a[0]+a[2], b[0]+b[2]) - x
  h = min(a[1]+a[3], b[1]+b[3]) - y
  if w<0 or h<0: return ()
  return (x, y, w, h)
```

Comment: Could you please improve your answer by adding some English sentences to explain what the code is doing? What are `a` and `b`? What is the meaning of the returned tuple?

Comment: Actually, There was same issue at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260892/finding-the-union-of-multiple-overlapping-rectangles-opencv-python?rq=1)